# How to test SSL switching using VS2010 on Win7

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, cassini

I developed a large web application with `VS2008` installed on an old `Win2k3 server`. I now have `Visual Studio 2010` installed on `Win7 Pro` and work on the application fine.

Parts of my web application need to switch into and out of `SSL` which they did on the `Win2k3 server` using the `IIS` tool that creates a private `SSL` cert.

However I now need to make changes to those parts and now **need** to be able to test it on the `VS2010` internal web server as I no longer have a `dev web server` like I used to. Is there any way I can do this or is it definitely a no no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of VS2010SP1 & IIS Express you can now to debug code that uses with https/SSL without having to use a FULL IIS server.

Answer (score 5):

Please take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943697.aspx). It is mentioned:

> This sample [some sample using HTTPS]
>   only works when hosted on IIS and
>   cannot work on Cassini – Visual Studio
>   Development Server because Cassini
>   does not support HTTPS.

As this sample is related to .Net Framework 4, I assume that Visual Studio 2010 does not support SSL.

EDIT: The good news is that you can enable SSL for IIS 7.0 (and above). You can find detailed instructions [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx).

When are done you should be able to access your website over SSL, but browsers will display a warning that says that your certificate is not trusted. However, this can be easily solved in the following way:

1) The common name (CN) for the self-signed certificate that you create for the website should match the computer name that runs IIS and you should access the site using the computer name (https://computerName/ not https://localhost/ or https://IP/)

2) Export the certificate from IIS and import it in the browsers certificate stores. For Internet Explorer the certificate must be added to Windows Certificate Store at Local Computer / Trusted Root Certification Authorities (use Windows Management Console). For other browsers, because they use custom certificate store, the certificate must be imported in their specific location. For example, in case of Firefox to import a certificate go to Tools->Option->Advanced->Encryption->View Certificates->Authorities->Import.

Comment: Thanks, so it's not possible. Well done Microsoft!  Developers can't test web applications switching SSL states in the dev environment. Not impressed! It should be built in to VS.

Comment: You are welcome! It seem that is not possible using Cassini, but you could enable SSL if you would use IIS 7 (and above) for development instead of the integrated web server. I have edited the initial answer adding details about this.