# Facebook app Debugging iis7 and ssl

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-2010, ssl, iis-7.5

I have a facebook application worked with iis7 and visual studio2010
I have been able to debug the application with w3wp attached till recently.
Since installed ssl with iis i have not been able to work with vs2010 and debugger.
Any suggestions appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem in the past with certificates and had to attach it manually to processes.  Have you seen this blog post before? 
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2007/10/18/visual-studio-debugging-websites-that-require-client-certificates.aspx

There is also a good StackOverflow question about this: 
  [How to test SSL switching using VS2010 on Win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023220/how-to-test-ssl-switching-using-vs2010-on-win7)

-liam